# simple update from

Tags: sql, postgresql

Cant figure this simple sql out.  crm_contact_id is updated with the same contact id throughout the table.  I'm trying to get it to equal what the from query equals when I do the select.

```
update events set crm_contact_id = c.id
from events as evts
inner join crm2.crm_retail_lead l on l.lead_number = evts.old_lead_number
inner join crm_contacts c on c.old_contact_id = l.contact_id
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: with no db setup at my end, can you tell what you would get if you execute this statement at your end....SELECT c.Id from events as evts inner join crm2.crm_retail_lead l on l.lead_number = evts.old_lead_number inner join crm_contacts c on c.old_contact_id = l.contact_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
UPDATE events... FROM events as evts JOIN [other tables]
```

you get two unrelated instances of the *events* table.
That's probably not what you want. A fixed version would look like this:

```
update events evts set crm_contact_id = c.id
from crm2.crm_retail_lead l 
inner join crm_contacts c on c.old_contact_id = l.contact_id
where l.lead_number = evts.old_lead_number
```

Comment: Perfect.  I can see where I was making my mistake.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have not placed any `WHERE` clause in query.....Make query with `where` clause

```
update events set crm_contact_id = c.id
from events as evts
inner join crm2.crm_retail_lead l on l.lead_number = evts.old_lead_number
inner join crm_contacts c on c.old_contact_id = l.contact_id
WHERE column_name='value'
```